# Memory goes on Increasing each time the interstitial ad is display in unity 5

Tags: c#, xcode, unity-game-engine

I am using google admob for showing interstitial ads in unity 5. I download the googleads mobile unity package and googlemobileadssdkios from github. I build and run the game in Xcode it shows banner ads and interstitial ads. I am using debug navigator to view the memory consumption each time the ads is loaded and closed. I noticed that the memory consumption is increasing each time the interstitial ad is loaded. That means memory does not get free up while closing the interstitial ads.

I have change nothing in the source code downloaded from github. If memory goes increasing in this pattern, the application will be terminated due to insufficient memory. So, how to free up the memory after the interstitial ad is closed?

Comment: Please point to the source of code, mostly need explicit release by calling Dispose or Finalizer Invocation

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is likely how you use the `InterstitialAd` API. You will get memory leak if not used correctly.

If you are creating new interstitial instance inside a function and the instance variable is declared as a local variable, you have to call the `Destroy` function of the interstitial class before the end of the function or before you lose the reference to the interstitial class.

For example:

```
void showAdFunction()
{

    InterstitialAd interstitial = new InterstitialAd(adUnitId);
    AdRequest request = new AdRequest.Builder().Build();
    //.... 
    interstitial.LoadAd(request);
    interstitial.Destroy(); //Must do this before losing the reference
}
```

Now, If the you have the `InterstitialAd` instance as a global variable and the script it is inside is being destroyed by  another script, you have to destroy the `InterstitialAd` instance as well in the `OnDestroy` function.

```
private InterstitialAd interstitial;

void showAdFunction()
{

    interstitial = new InterstitialAd(adUnitId);
    AdRequest request = new AdRequest.Builder().Build();
    //....   
    interstitial.LoadAd(request);
}

void OnDestroy()
{
    interstitial.Destroy(); //Destroy
}
```

Comment: thank you. As you said, I call interstitial.Destroy() function at different places like , showInterstitial(), HandleAdFailedToLoad(),HandleAdClosed(),HandleAdLeftApplication(). And it works for me.

Comment: Nice. Glad I was able to help.