# how to bring back an ad (adMob) once you have destroyed it?

Tags: unity-game-engine, admob

This is the first time I have implemented ads. I am using adMob.  I have been messing around with the different code pieces, but I can't seem to create a new ad, if I have destroyed it.

```
private void RequestInterstitial()
{
    // These ad units are configured to always serve test ads.
    #if UNITY_EDITOR
    string adUnitId = "unused";
#elif UNITY_ANDROID
    string adUnitId = "ca-app-pub-3895731736666139/7005438200";
#elif UNITY_IPHONE
    string adUnitId = "hmm";
#else
    string adUnitId = "unexpected_platform";
#endif

    // Create an interstitial.
    this.interstitial = new InterstitialAd(adUnitId);

    // Register for ad events.
    this.interstitial.OnAdLoaded += this.HandleInterstitialLoaded;
    this.interstitial.OnAdFailedToLoad += this.HandleInterstitialFailedToLoad;
    this.interstitial.OnAdOpening += this.HandleInterstitialOpened;
    this.interstitial.OnAdClosed += this.HandleInterstitialClosed;
    this.interstitial.OnAdLeavingApplication += this.HandleInterstitialLeftApplication;

    // Load an interstitial ad.
    this.interstitial.LoadAd(this.CreateAdRequest());
}

private void ShowInterstitial()
{
    if (this.interstitial.IsLoaded())
    {
        this.interstitial.Show();
    }
    else
    {
        MonoBehaviour.print("Interstitial is not ready yet");
        text.text = "No Ad Loaded";
    }
}
```

Now to destroy

```
this.interstitial.Destroy();
```

Does the Destroy function get called when you click the "x" on the interstitial?

Then how do I bring it back?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Does the Destroy function get called when you click the "x" on the
>   interstitial?

**No**. Very unlikely. If this is true then you will have to perform `new InterstitialAd(adUnitId);` each time before showing ad again. When x is clicked, it is very likely that `InterstitialAd.Hide();` is called.

> I have been messing around with the different code pieces, but I can't
>   seem to create a new ad, if I have destroyed it.
>
> Then how do I bring it back?

You should never destroy it unless interstitial declaration is out of scope then you should call `interstitial.Destroy()`.

*For example*:

If interstitial is declared in a function then you must destroy it at the end of that function to avoid memory leak.

If interstitial is declared outside a function/global variable you should only destroy it in in the Unity `OnDisable()` function. In your case, it is a global variable, so must put `interstitial.Destroy()` inside the  `OnDisable()` function so that when your script destroys, it will destroy `interstitial` too.

Now, if you end up destroying interstitial, you can bring it back by doing `interstitial = new InterstitialAd(adUnitId);` again, then call `interstitial.LoadAd()` followed by `interstitial.Show()`. Before calling `interstitial.Show()`, you must first check if it has finished loading with `if(interstitial.IsLoaded())` before calling `interstitial.Show()`.

Finally, when you register for an event, you should as well un-register the event in the `OnDisable()` function. You register with `+=` and un-register with `-=`. So you should do that with `this.interstitial.OnAdLoaded -= this.HandleInterstitialLoaded;` and other events in the `OnDisable()` function too before calling `interstitial.Destroy()`.

Comment: Thanks that was helpful!

Comment: You are welcome. Yo can get a sample code of what I just talked about from [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/39882989/3785314)